# Python [WinError3]

Tags: python

I am trying to get into Python coding and set up a loop to name files after the current date. I encountered a problem, however, in trying to name the files. Whenever I try to run this script, I get the error message "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'D:\Python Scripts\text.txt' -> '05/13/2017'" Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

```
import time
import os

x = 1
directory = "D:\\Python Scripts"
item = "text.txt"
path = os.path.join(directory, item) 

while x == 1:
    date = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

    file = open("text.txt","w+")

    file.close()

    file = os.rename(path, date)                   


    x = x + 1
```

Comment: D:\\Python Scripts

rename the directory as spaces create problem, use underscore for the directory python_scripts like this

Comment: ‘filelink = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), 'D:\\', 'Python Scripts\\', 'Text.txt'))‘

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `/` is not a valid character in a Windows filename. You can verify this by trying to do the rename manually in File Explorer. It will fail there too, but with a more useful message. Use

`date = time.strftime("%m_%d_%Y")`

instead.